# VisualSVN Server post-commit hook script to send an email notification

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

Can someone help me in posting some VisualSVN post-commit hook scripts to send a mail whenever there is some changes in a file in repository?

Answer (score 2):

See KB18 (Configuring Email Notifications in VisualSVN Server):
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/